# nohup multiple command in cluster

Tags: linux, nohup

I want to run multiple command background in my cluster as follows. But it's interrupted and not successful completion.

```
nohup perl sgfa.pl -i 1.fa   & sleep 1
nohup perl sgfa.pl -i 2.fa   & sleep 1
nohup perl sgfa.pl -i 3.fa   & sleep 1
```

why? Any suggest is hope. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that:
/usr/bin/nohup $(/bin/bash -c 'for i in {1..3}; do /usr/bin/perl sgfa.pl -i $i.fa& /bin/sleep 1; done')&

What is the error message you get?

Comment: not any error message, just interrupted and not resulted.

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that nouhp redirects stdout and stderr to nohup.out in the cwd, or $HOME/nohup.out ?

Try replacing your script with a script that should create a file. Is the file created?